# How to iterate over a List<DTO> and get the DTO attribute values dynamically?

Tags: java, list, properties, iteration

```
private void writeData(HSSFSheet sheet) {
        for (int i = 0; i < boltData.size(); i++) {
            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowCount);
            rowCount++;
            BoltDto boltDto = boltData.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < **${noOfattributesInMyEntity}**; j++) {
                HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(j);
                cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(
                        (**boltDto.getXyz()**).trim()));
            }
        }
    }
```

I want something like above.

I am creating an excel sheet where in the number of rows corresponds to the number of objects in the List. and the number of columns corresponds to the number of attributes/properties in the DTO.

As my DTO has over 40 attributes, I don't want to write explicitly. Is there any work around?

Comment: have you tried using reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection or (better) the [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) API (or anything providing similar functionality). The simplest usage would look like this:

```
for (Object property : BeanUtils.describe(yourDto).keySet()) {
    Object value = BeanUtils.getProperty(yourDto, property.toString());
    // do whatever with the property value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reflection APIs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.htm) to find members and/or methods.

If you literally want to take all members this may well be enough. If you need some king of selectivity you may need co-operation from the DTO author, did they use a naming convention? Is there any additional meta data?

Comment: I'm the DTO author. I've the full control.